# How to calculate angular velocity about a second axis?

Tags: reference-frames, vectors, coordinate-systems, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

A point in space at $(a,b)$ revolves around the origin with an angular velocity omega. I wish to compute its angular velocity about a second axis, running parallel to the $z$ axis at point $(x,y)$. Obviously, this depends on the position (a,b) such that at point (a',b'), its angular velocity will be different than at point (a,b). Since the position depends on time, there should be a way to compute the angular velocity about axis (x,y) as a function of time. What is it?

Comment: Angular velocity is usually defined for rotation around an axis (not point). Could you rephrase your question accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

When you say angular velocity about a point you mean to say angular velocity about an axis. The equation is simple: $\omega =\frac{\vec{r} \times\vec{v} }{|r^2|} $ where $ \vec{r}$ is the position vector from the axis(through a point) that you choose and $ \vec{v} $ is  velocity vector.

Comment: If it's particle's orbit is circular, then the equation becomes simpler: $\omega = \frac{v}{r}$